# I can't change color in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I tried to make a SVG animation.
But It can't change color in SVG element when I clicked Red Cheeks button.
Maybe, I think that javascript selector is wrong. Because sometimes, it worked only LeftCheek when I used querySelectorAll method.

And console showed this error message. but I can't understand how I fix it.

`main.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined(…)changeCharactor @ main.js:11`

My code is [here](http://codepen.io/kwonkwon/pen/JbyvJw)(code pen).

If my explain is unclear, Please comments.
Thanks :-)

Comment: please include key code inline in your question - links are good but extra

Answer (score 1):

The `cheek` variable is set to a DOMList, which is sort of like an array of elements.

```
var cheek = document.getElementsByClassName("cheeks");
```

As such, it doesn't have a `classList` property. Instead, individual elements of the list have that property.

```
cheek[0].classList.add('...whatever');
```

Comment: Cool!! It works! I understand your comment. Thanks a lot :-)